# sent 1011 (unexpected error) keepalive ping timeout; no close frame received - websockets python

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

i m getting the following error: "sent 1011 (unexpected error) keepalive ping timeout; no close frame received". after connecting the websocket server.

as per my understanding it is because server is not getting ping on regular interval. i m sending the ping on every 20 secs. below is my code please help me to resolve the issue.

```
self.ws = await websockets.connect(self.ROOT_URI, extra_headers=self.header,logger=logging.getLogger("websockets.client"),
                                   ping_interval=30)

pong = await self.ws.ping("ping")
print(await pong)
```

Thank you

```
self.ws = await websockets.connect(self.ROOT_URI, extra_headers=self.header,logger=logging.getLogger("websockets.client"),
                                   ping_interval=30)

pong = await self.ws.ping("ping")
print(await pong)
```